# How do i add data to a database, am trying to test

Tags: php, mysql

```
<? 
require_once('includes/inc_auth2.php');
require_once('includes/config.php');

authRegister($Tawanda, $Mukoko, $dob, $gender, $email, $password);



//requesting from database
/*require_once('includes/db.php');

function authRegister($forename, $surname, $dob, $gender, $email, $password){


    $addUser = "INSERT INTO user (forename, surname, dob, gender, email) VALUES ('$forename', '$surname', '$dob', '$gender','$email)";
            //Execute the mysql query and store it in a variable called '$result'
            $result = mysql_query($addUser);

}*/
     ?>
```

Comment: Okay, well maybe more information is required. Do you get some error messages? What exactly is not working? What framework you are using (if any) and what about your database schema?

Comment: +1 Olli for combination of courtesy and sarcasm.

Comment: what does your `includes/db.php` look like? (sans username, host and password, of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Oli said: we need a bit more info.

However, some first steps to try are to get a sample query (add an `echo $addUser;` and copy it when you run the php) and paste it into your db input (phpMyAdmin, command line, or other similar tool for directly managing the database) and see if you are getting any errors there (sometimes PHP fails silently if the query is generating an error with the db, especially if you aren't accessing the `$result` at all).

The most likely issue is that your SQL is malformed (again, hard to tell without knowing your schema)

Answer (score 0):

use the php [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function